# serve_site changes CSS to its default values in blogdown

Tags: css, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I'm creating a `blogdown` website using [agency theme](https://github.com/digitalcraftsman/hugo-agency-theme) and everything works fine.

I changed some stuff in the `CSS`, located in `public/css/agency.css` and I can see all changes. However, when I restarted RStudio all changes I've made switch to their default values (colors and stuff). And the same happens if I run `blogdown::serve_site()`

I can't see what's going wrong with my approach and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not touch the `public` directory. It is automatically generated from your website source files (see [Section 1.2 of the blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html) for some basics). If you want to change anything on your website, always change the source. In your case, you can either change the CSS file in the theme (personally I don't recommend this way), or provide your own `static/css/agency.css` to override your theme's CSS. For more about the overriding mechanism, see [Section 2.7](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html).

Comment: Thank you @Yihui. You're always active here and ready to help.